# incorrect Cypher query and the function node()

Tags: neo4j

i have a problem with the following Cypher query:

```
match (m:Person) where m.number=42 with id(m) as var start p=node(var) return p
```

gives: Invalid input 'v': expected whitespace, an unsigned integer, a parameter or '*'

i just know the "number" of a "Person" and want to get the complete node of this "Person"
with only one Cypher-Statement...

Thx in advance

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question, the one that you want answered. Christophe has answered this question (as written).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply get the node with the match statement :

```
MATCH (m:Person) WHERE m.number = 42 RETURN m;
```